# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Tags: php, mysqli

```
Receive 3 Warnings: mysqli_query() for function create_tb(), first       parameters are "CREATE TABLE session id ()" and "CREATE TABLE user ()" on   lines 151 and 170 haven't a clue what the second would be?
```

There was also the mysqli_error() on line 170?

errors

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\line   151
```

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\line 170
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\line 170

```
enter code here

function create_tb()
{
// This function creates all the nessesary tables for database
global $db_link, $host_name, $db_user,$db_password,
$html_header, $html_footer, $db_name, $table_ads; 
$sql_query1=sql_create_tb();
$db_link = mysqli_connect($host_name, $db_user, $db_password);
mysqli_query($db_link, $sql_query1);                     

mysqli_query ("
CREATE TABLE session_id (
 id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 cookie varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 user_id int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
 last_request int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (id),
 UNIQUE KEY id (id)
 )");                                                      //line 151

mysqli_query ("
CREATE TABLE user (
 id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 user_name text NOT NULL,
 email text NOT NULL,
 passwd text NOT NULL,
 tel text NOT NULL,
 fax text NOT NULL,
 city text NOT NULL,
 state text NOT NULL,
 ip text NOT NULL,
 category text NOT NULL,
 lastup_date int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
 member_date int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (id),
 UNIQUE KEY id (id)
 )") or die (mysqli_error());                             //line 170
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give db connection identifier as first argument. Eg:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM xxxxx");
```

Comment: The connection identifier was missing. errors solved, Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explicit : You need 2 parameters :
- the connection identifier 
- the query.

E.g :

```
mysqli_query ($db_link, "
CREATE TABLE session_id (
 id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 cookie varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
 user_id int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
 last_request int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (id),
 UNIQUE KEY id (id)
 )");
```

Without the first parameter, the mysqli function does not know which database to use so it displays you the error above